# T-SQL Dynamic Query and pivot

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have data where people have changed role mid month and want to count the activity after their new start date. Can I use the results of a table as a dynamic Query, I have a query which returns the following resultset:-

```
Firstname    Surname    StartDate
----------------------------------
Jon          Smith      2015-01-01
Paul         Jones      2014-07-23
...
```

So the query would look something like:

```
SELECT Firstname +' '+ surname, month,  count(1) FROM dataTable
WHERE (Firstname='John' AND Surname='Smith' AND date >=2015-01-01)
OR (Firstname='Paul' AND Surname='Jones' AND date >=2014-07-23)
OR ...
```

but the number of 'ORs' would depend on the number of rows in the first table

```
Name        Month   Count
----------------------------------
Jon Smith   1       15
Paul Jones  1       16
Jon Smith   2       30
Paul Jones  2       25
Charlie Gu  1       52
```

Which I can then pivot to get

```
Name          1      2
--------------------------
Jon Smith     15     30
Paul Jones    16     25
Charlie Gu    52     NULL
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: I guess you can achieve creating a dynamic query by declaring a varchar variable for your query and iterate over the data you want in your "or clause". Afterward execute the built-in stored procedure "exec sp_executesql @yourquery"

Comment: Maybe I missed something, what is the reason why you want to create a dynamic query instead of joining the table that contains start- enddate and the role of the employee?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that [Ako](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4520320/ako) is right and a simple join should do the trick rather than a dynamic query.

```
declare @NewStartDates table
    (
     Firstname nvarchar(100),
     Surname nvarchar(100),
     StartDate date
    );

insert  into @NewStartDates
        (Firstname, Surname, StartDate)
values  (N'Jon', N'Smith', '20150101'),
        (N'Paul', N'Jones', '20140723');

select  d.Firstname,
        d.Surname,
        year(d.Date) * 100 + month(d.Date) as Period,
        count(*) as ActivityCount
from    dataTable as d
inner join @NewStartDates as n
        on d.Firstname = n.Firstname
           and d.Surname = n.Surname
           and d.Date >= n.StartDate
group by d.Firstname,
        d.Surname,
        year(d.Date) * 100 + month(d.Date);
```

Answer (score 0):

Please refer this - it will give you complete idea how you can get dynamic column query.[Dynamic Column Generation - Pivot [SQL]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46947431/i-want-to-generate-sql-query-output-like-screenshot/46952452#46952452)